# jenkins is not showing login page after new installation setup with ubuntu 16.04

Tags: jenkins

I just installed Jenkins in my system OS ubuntu 16.04 and while set admin username password Jenkins is not showing anything on a webpage, please share the solution for that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you really assume that we know THE solution for your problem based on the amount of information that you provided?

Answer (score 0):

Try and make sure that Jenkins is up to date and restart while checking logs. The operating system does not matter in this scenario but the java version does. Make sure you are running Java 1.8

Comment: My issue has been resolved but I have to use default port number 8080, if I am changing it another port number, Jenkins will not work.